# Prevent renders when updated state is same as previous

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-class-based-component

Is there a react lifecycle method that we can use to perform a re-render only when the updated state is different from the previous state. For example, in the following code:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      value: "abcd"
    };
  }

  handlePress = () => {
    this.setState({ value: "abcd" });
  };

  render() {
    console.log("render");
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.value}</h1>
        <button onClick={this.handlePress}>Press</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

You can see that on pressing the button, even though the state is the same as the previous, it will still lead to the `render()` function running.

I know that we can use `shouldComponentUpdate()` or `PureComponent` to prevent that but are there other ways/lifecycle methods that can achieve this?

I have also created a sandbox/playground of the above code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-shadow-xld6h8).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using functional components, you can use `React.memo` to achieve this.

```
import React, { useState, memo } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("abcd");

  const handlePress = () => {
    setValue("abcd");
  };

  console.log("render");

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{value}</h1>
      <button onClick={handlePress}>Press</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default memo(App);
```

For class components, you can use `shouldComponentUpdate`, but you'd have to manually compare the changes.

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  return nextState.value !== this.state.value;
}
```

#### Edit

React.memo only tracks the props, not state.

Thanks @Oktay Yuzcan for pointing it out.

Comment: Is it possible to use any lifecycle method other than `shouldComponentUpdate` for this?

Comment: React memo does not prevent rerender after state change. It prevents rerender when the props are unchanged.

Comment: @OktayYuzcan that's exactly what the OP requested

Comment: The OP asks how to prevent rerender when state changes. How memo does that?

Comment: OP wants to perform a re-render only when the updated state is different from the previous state

Comment: Exactly. React memo tracks props, not state

Comment: yea you're right good catch